# Transform XML with XSLT but only certain nodes, attributes,

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a source XML file here and want to transform it using XSLT. Since the original XML file is quite complex.

I try to transform it with Eclipse. Here my XSL Code.
That the goal of the transformation is that another program can now read the structured XML.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="1.0">

        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

        <!-- Copy everything -->
        <xsl:template match="*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <!-- Do some adjustments for the address -->
        <xsl:template match="packagedElement">
            <xsl:element name="Adresse">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>

        <!-- here I try to select the ownedAttribute node and select only the Name(s) however it doesn´t work out  -->
    <xsl:template match="//ownedAttribute[@name='quelle1']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>


        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my source XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="20131001" 

<uml:Model xmi:id="_UMyDIP-vEeiYTffJXPS1ig" name="Fallbeispiel1">

</packageImport>
    <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="_f7jXYP-vEeiYTffJXPS1ig" name="Produktion" classifierBehavior="_qcIkwP-wEeiYTffJXPS1ig">
      <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_K8DCIP-wEeiYTffJXPS1ig" name="quelle1" type="_h4oIEP-vEeiYTffJXPS1ig"/>

</xmi:XMI>
```

.
.
.
.

My result should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

-<xmi:XMI xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmi:version="2.0">


-<Block name="Produktion">

<property name="quelle1"/>

<property name="maschine1" />

<property name="foerdereinrichtung1" />
```

My goal for ownedAttribute is to allow only the output of the name.

Comment: You will get more answer if you post a better (complete) input sample and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input you have given is not well-formed. It's also missing some namespace declarations.

Though I am assuming the input source as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="20131001" 
         xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI"
         xmlns:uml="href://org.omg/UML/1.3">

<uml:Model xmi:id="_UMyDIP-vEeiYTffJXPS1ig" name="Fallbeispiel1">
    <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="_f7jXYP-vEeiYTffJXPS1ig" name="Produktion" classifierBehavior="_qcIkwP-wEeiYTffJXPS1ig">
        <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_K8DCIP-wEeiYTffJXPS1ig" name="quelle1" type="_h4oIEP-vEeiYTffJXPS1ig" />
        <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_K8DCIP-wEeiYTffJXPS1ig" name="maschine1" type="_h4oIEP-vEeiYTffJXPS1ig" />
    </packagedElement>
</uml:Model>
```

And modified your xslt to achieve the expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
            xmlns:uml="href://org.omg/UML/1.3"
            xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<!-- Copy everything -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Do some adjustments for the address -->
<xsl:template match="packagedElement">
    <xsl:element name="Block">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- here I try to select the ownedAttribute node and select only the Name(s) however it doesn´t work out -->
<xsl:template match="ownedAttribute">
    <xsl:element name="property">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="uml:Model">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See the demo here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq6y

Let me know if I'm missing something or this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Note that the body of the `match="ownedAttribute"` template could be simplified to `<property name="{@name}"><xsl:apply-templates/></property>`